# Can't find my crypto by name only by contract

Tags: solidity, remix

I have recently made a crypto coin using eth remix but when I try to search it up on BscScan or poo coin I can't find it I can only find it if I paste the contract how can I fix this?

Comment: what is the address of your smart contract?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I recall, those entities start indexing the coin by name after x amount of time / searches. I recommend you follow the docs of bscScan:

https://docs.bscscan.com/api-endpoints/contracts